# Categorization by median within groups

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, case

Lets assume a data like this below

```
ID  Quantity    Group     Indicator
1   0.93        Red       1
2   0.17        Red       1
3   0.01        Red       0
4   0.44        Red       1
5   0.01        Red       0
6   0.86        Red       1
7   0.07        Red       1
8   0.02        Red       0   
9   1.00        Red       1
1   0.65        Blue      1
2   0.17        Blue      1
3   0.02        Blue      0
4   0.01        Blue      0
5   0.09        Blue      1
6   0.86        Blue      1
7   0.05        Blue      0
8   0.23        Blue      1
9   0.01        Blue      0
```

Now I want to create a new column with three values/categories.

- 1  if the indicator column value is 0
- 3  if the indicator column value is 1 and values in column Quantity is at or above the median (median of  Quantity for all values where indicator ==1).
- 2  if the indicator column value is 1 and values in column Quantity is at or below the median (median of  Quantity for all values where indicator ==1).

This logic to be applied for values in Group separately.

Expecting an output like this.

median of all values in Quantity where Indicator == 1 for Group Red.
median(0.93, 0.17,0.44,0.86,0.07,1.00) = 0.65

median of all values in Quantity where Indicator == 1 for Group Blue.
median(0.65, 0.17,0.09,0.86,0.23) = 0.23

```
ID  Quantity    Group     Indicator   Results
1   0.93        Red       1           3   <- Above the median(0.65) for all values in red where Indicator ==1
2   0.17        Red       1           2   <- Below the median(0.65) for all values in red where Indicator ==1
3   0.01        Red       0           1
4   0.44        Red       1           2   <- Below the median(0.65) for all values in red where Indicator ==1
5   0.01        Red       0           1
6   0.86        Red       1           3   <- Above the median(0.65) for all values in red where Indicator ==1
7   0.07        Red       1           2   <- Below the median(0.65) for all values in red where Indicator ==1
8   0.02        Red       0           1
9   1.00        Red       1           3   <- Above the median(0.65) for all values in red where Indicator ==1

1   0.65        Blue      1           3
2   0.17        Blue      1           2
3   0.02        Blue      0           1
4   0.01        Blue      0           1
5   0.09        Blue      1           2
6   0.86        Blue      1           3
7   0.05        Blue      0           1
8   0.23        Blue      1           2
9   0.01        Blue      0           1
```

I have tried this with bunch of ifelse and it is very clumsy. Looking for something efficient with case_when. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `dplyr` approach to achieve your desired result may look like so:

```
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

dat |> 
  mutate(
    Results = case_when(
      Indicator == 0 ~ 1,
     Quantity <= median(Quantity) ~ 2,
     .default = 3
    ),
    .by = c(Group, Indicator)
  )
#>    ID Quantity Group Indicator Results
#> 1   1     0.93   Red         1       3
#> 2   2     0.17   Red         1       2
#> 3   3     0.01   Red         0       1
#> 4   4     0.44   Red         1       2
#> 5   5     0.01   Red         0       1
#> 6   6     0.86   Red         1       3
#> 7   7     0.07   Red         1       2
#> 8   8     0.02   Red         0       1
#> 9   9     1.00   Red         1       3
#> 10  1     0.65  Blue         1       3
#> 11  2     0.17  Blue         1       2
#> 12  3     0.02  Blue         0       1
#> 13  4     0.01  Blue         0       1
#> 14  5     0.09  Blue         1       2
#> 15  6     0.86  Blue         1       3
#> 16  7     0.05  Blue         0       1
#> 17  8     0.23  Blue         1       2
#> 18  9     0.01  Blue         0       1
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
  Quantity = c(0.93, 0.17, 0.01, 0.44, 0.01, 0.86, 0.07, 0.02, 1.00, 0.65, 0.17, 0.02, 0.01, 0.09, 0.86, 0.05, 0.23, 0.01),
  Group = c("Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue"),
  Indicator = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0)
)
```

Comment: I believe that the medians are computed by groups of `Group` only, not by indicator.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Always good to double check. But according to the OP the median should be the *median of Quantity for all values where indicator ==1*

Comment: After reading again you are probably right but this is a point that is not completely clear (in my mind).

Answer (score 2):

Another `dplyr` option with some logical arithmetic:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Results = Indicator * (1 + (Quantity > median(Quantity))) + 1,
         .by = c(Group, Indicator))

#    ID Quantity Group Indicator Results
# 1   1     0.93   Red         1       3
# 2   2     0.17   Red         1       2
# 3   3     0.01   Red         0       1
# 4   4     0.44   Red         1       2
# 5   5     0.01   Red         0       1
# 6   6     0.86   Red         1       3
# 7   7     0.07   Red         1       2
# 8   8     0.02   Red         0       1
# 9   9     1.00   Red         1       3
# 10  1     0.65  Blue         1       3
# 11  2     0.17  Blue         1       2
# 12  3     0.02  Blue         0       1
# 13  4     0.01  Blue         0       1
# 14  5     0.09  Blue         1       2
# 15  6     0.86  Blue         1       3
# 16  7     0.05  Blue         0       1
# 17  8     0.23  Blue         1       2
# 18  9     0.01  Blue         0       1
```